# Methods to remove deviations while calculating exponents?

Tags: c

I was solving some a question on LeetCode. This is my code

```
    
    int f;
    f =(x<0)?-1:1;
    float e = pow(10,(n*log10(f*x)));
    
    if(f==-1 && n%2!=0)
        return(-e);
        
    return(e);

}
```

My problem is that for x=8.66731 and n=4, my code gives an output 5643.35449 but the expected output is 5643.35434. How do I improve the accuracy or "iron out" this deviation? Also, any ways to improve my code?

Comment: Suggestion: use `double` (or even `long double`) throughout; forget `float`.

Comment: What's wrong with `return pow(x, n);`?

Comment: I can confirm that using double gives the expected result.

Comment: Using double does solve this problem. Thanks a lot! @pmg

Comment: Suggestion: forget `float` for the rest of your career, not just this snippet :-) *unless you do embedded or other restricted environments*

Comment: And remember that `double` is the default type for floating point constant values and arguments for variadic functions. Never use `float` without a very good reason, even if the textbook writers seem to be stuck in 1980. The library function have versions for `float` such as `powf()` but the arguments for and return value for `pow()` are `double`. Note too that your `float` usage was good for 7 decimal digits which is all you get.